# LibCurl C++: slowing down the sending of requests when multiplexing

Tags: c++, web-scraping, libcurl, http2, multiplexing

**Goal:**

To slightly slow down the sending of requests when `multiplexing` with `libcurl`, possibly by introducing small time delays in between the sending of each of the `HTTP/2` request to a server. The multiplexing program needs to listen out for any changes from **one webpage** for around 3 seconds at a set time once a day. However, the multiplexing program finishes execution in under a second even when setting the variable `num_transfers` to the thousands (variable seen in the code further below).

It would be useful if there was a way to introduce for example, a `3 millisecond` delay in between the transmission of a group of multiplex requests. This would mean the program could still send requests `asynchronously` (so it be won't blocked / won't have to wait for a response from the server before sending the next request) but at a slightly slower rate.

A definition of `multiplexing` [taken from this resource](http://qnimate.com/what-is-multiplexing-in-http2/):

> Multiplexing is a method in HTTP/2 by which multiple HTTP requests can be sent and responses can be received asynchronously via a single TCP connection. Multiplexing is the heart of HTTP/2 protocol.

**Ideal outcome:**

An ideal program for this situation would be one that could send a few non-blocking/ multiplex requests every approx. 3 milliseconds. The program would run for around 3-4 seconds in total.

**Current problem:**

Currently the program is too fast when multiplexing, meaning a few thousand requests could be sent and received within around `350 milliseconds` **which can lead to the sending IP address to be blocked for a few minutes.**.

**Please note** it is not an option in this scenario to use a synchronous / blocking approach - a requirement of this program is that it **must not** be forced to wait for a response to be returned before sending another request. The issue lies in the fact that the program is too fast at sending a high number of requests.

**Attempts at solving:**

In the `DO...WHILE` loop seen in the code below, an attempt was made to introduce some artificial time delays at various locations within the loop using `usleep(microseconds)` from `unistd.h`, but this introduced a time delay either before or after all of the requests were sent, rather than an interleaved time delay between sending requests.

**Current code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <chrono>

#include <string>

/* somewhat unix-specific */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* curl stuff */
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/mprintf.h>

#ifndef CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX
#define CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX 0
#endif

struct CURLMsg *msg;

struct transfer {
    CURL *easy;
    unsigned int num;
    //FILE *out;
    std::string contents;
};

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

struct MemoryStruct chunk;

#define NUM_HANDLES 1000

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    transfer *t = (transfer *)userp;
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;    
    t->contents.append((const char*)contents, realsize);
    return realsize;
}

static void setup(struct transfer *t, int num)
{
    CURL *hnd;

    hnd = t->easy = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)t);

    /* set the same URL */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://someurl.xyz");

    /* HTTP/2 please */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);

    /* we use a self-signed test server, skip verification during debugging */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    #if (CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX > 0)
    /* wait for pipe connection to confirm */
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT, 1L);
    #endif
}

int main() {
    struct transfer trans[NUM_HANDLES];
    CURLM *multi_handle;
    int i;
    int still_running = 0; /* keep number of running handles */
    int num_transfers = 3;

    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;

    /* init a multi stack */
    multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

    for(i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
        setup(&trans[i], i);

        /* add the individual transfer */
        curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, trans[i].easy);
    }

    curl_multi_setopt(multi_handle, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX);
//  curl_multi_setopt(multi_handle, CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 1L);

    // Main loop
    do {

        CURLMcode mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

        if(still_running) {
            /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
            mc = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
        }

        if(mc) {
            break;
        }

        // Get response
        do {
            int queued;
            msg = curl_multi_info_read(multi_handle, &queued);
            if ((msg) && (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) && (msg->data.result == CURLE_OK)) {

                // Get size of payload
                curl_off_t dl_size;
                curl_easy_getinfo(msg->easy_handle, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD_T, &dl_size);

                    for (int i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
                        std::cout << trans[i].contents;
                    }
                    std::cout << std::flush;
            }
            
        } while (msg);

    } while (still_running);

    for(i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, trans[i].easy);
        curl_easy_cleanup(trans[i].easy);
    }

    free(chunk.memory);
    curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);
        
    return 0;
}
```

**Summary question:**

Is there a way to send a group of multiplexed requests to a single URL approximately every 3 milliseconds? Another idea to attempt to solve this was to wrap the entire functionality contained in `main()` within a `FOR` loop, and putting a time delay at the end of each iteration of the `FOR` loop.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Keep in mind that the system most likely will sleep longer than you wanted it to. Depending on your use case that may not be a problem.